# how do I bridge two wired network connections

Tags: networking, network-bridge, wired

I have an EVGA 780i SLI motherboard with dual ethernet ports.  I was just wondering if there was a way to bridge them like I can in Windows?

Comment: Could you explain a bit what do you mean with *bridge* two connections? What is behind both connections? Two PCs, two routers, one of each, or what?

Answer (score 1):

`bridge-utils` package in Ubuntu should help you get started with bridging network connections. It will require editing a few configuration files and running some commands with appropriate privileges.

For more details refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge

There is no easy way to do it by right-clicking in the GUI as with Windows. There could be tools that help doing this, but I am not aware of any of them being available in a standard Ubuntu installation.